# Is it possible to display newly generated password after wp_generate_password()?

Tags: password

```
$np = wp_generate_password();       
wp_set_password( $np, $user_id );
$messagetouser = 'Reset succeeeded. The new password is: ' . $np;
```

Above code is a part of resetpassword-functionality.
Above code works, BUT how to achieve to display the new password to the user? (The password display now is the one generated and used by the db?)

It might not be possible? I guess it's not...

but in which circumstances would you need `wp_generate_password()` then ?

Answer (score 0):

By default when a users submits a [password reset](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-login.php#L559) from [wp-login.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-login.php), [reset_password](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-login.php#L605) is called. In [user.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/user.php),  [`reset_password()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/reset_password/) triggers the [`password_reset`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/password_reset) hook where you can see the plain text version before it is set. And the same for [`after_password_reset`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_password_reset/).

```
add_action( 'password_reset', 'my_password_reset', 10, 2 );

function my_password_reset( $user, $new_pass ) {
    // Do something before password reset.
}
```

[`wp_set_password()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_password/) immediately runs [`wp_hash_password()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_hash_password/) and is entered into the database as encrypted text. The hooks above are the last time you can see the plain text version of the password.

```
function wp_hash_password($password) {
    global $wp_hasher;

    if ( empty($wp_hasher) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php');
        // By default, use the portable hash from phpass
        $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
    }

    return $wp_hasher->HashPassword( trim( $password ) );
}
```

When the operation is complete, the [login_header](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-login.php#L607) is set to 'Your password has been reset.'.

As you can see, using [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) or [`get_user_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) will only show you the encrypted version later on.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
echo $user->data->user_pass;

$user = get_user_by ('id', 1 );
echo $user->data->user_pass;
```

If you want to write a custom function using [`wp_generate_password()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/) then its up to you to do it in a way that shows the plain text version to the user, much like [wp-login.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-login.php) does.